# Bash: Adding the contents of a column to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk

So I have a file that contains some text, but there are some lines that contain only "Overall>5". (the number after > could be any number from 0 to 5).

The code I wrote:

```
let sumOfReviews=0

while read line; do awk -F ">" '{if($1=="Overall") ((sumOfReviews+=$2))}'; done<$file

echo $sumOfReviews
```

I tried splitting these lines into 2 columns at ">" and I want to add the number in the second column (5 in this case) to a variable. The problem is when I print out the value of the variable at the end it shows 0. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If called from the console, the following seems to do the job:

```
awk -F'>' '/Overall>[0-9]+/ { total += $2 } END { print total }' exampleData.txt
```

If you want to call it from inside `bash`, you have to enclose it in `$( ... )`:

```
#!/bin/bash

total="$(awk -F'>' '/Overall>[0-9]+/ { total += $2 } END { print total }' exampleData.txt)"

# do something with `total` here.
```

You cannot simply use `awk` as some sort of syntax inside `bash`, `awk` is a separate programming language, it is invoked as a completely separate process. You can try to build in some bash parameters into `awk`s source code though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a one line awk script.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=">"; sumOfReviews=0 } /^Overall>[0-5]/ { sumOfReviews+=$2 } END { print sumOfReviews }' < file
```

**Explanation from Manpage:**

An AWK program consists of a sequence of pattern-action statements and optional function definitions.

```
pattern   { action statements }
```

In this case we have used the **BEGIN** pattern to set the file separator to ">" and the sumOfReviews variable to 0.

We use the **/^Overall>[0-5]/** regular expression pattern to match lines beginning with "Overall>" followed by a number 0-5 and if true add the $2 field to the sumOfReviews variable.

Finally we use the **END** pattern to output the final sumOfReviews value.

---

**Example solution in a bash shell script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

noAuthors=4 # set to 4 for example

sumOfReviews=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS=">"; sumOfReviews=0 } /^Overall>[0-5]/ 
{ sumOfReviews+=$2 } END { print sumOfReviews }' < file)

echo $(($sumOfReviews/$noAuthors))
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer! From your code, it tells me that it doesn't recognize sumOfReviews as a command...

Comment: Interesting.. can you try making sure there's no spaces around the "=" sign, otherwise it's interpreted as a command eg. sumOfReviews=$(awk 'BEGIN ...

Comment: Nevermind, I was using spaces between the variable name and "=". It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`awk` and `bash` are two separate programs; they don't share variables. All you need is a single `awk` script:

```
awk -F '>' '$1 == "Overall" {reviews += $2}; END {print reviews}' "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working! Just a thought: I need to manipulate the value of "reviews" afterwards, can I use a pipe or something? I want to divide it by an already calculated number, stored in bash variable noAuthors. Sorry if it sounds so silly, I'm really at the beginning

Comment: @LorenaMitoi `awk` can do the math itself, but you need to set an awk variable based on the value of that shell variable. Something like `awk -v noAuthors="$noAuthors" -F '>' '$1 == "Overall" {reviews += $2}; END {print reviews/noAuthors}' "$file"